# Interleave disassembly + source with avr-objdump

Tags: avr-gcc, avr-toolchain

I have a C program for the attiny85, that I want to disassemble and display with interleaved source code.

Here's my program:
test.c

```
#include <avr/io.h>
int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        PORTB=i;
    }
}
```

Here's how I compile it: `avr-gcc -g -O0 -mmcu=attiny85 -o test.elf test.c`

Finally, I generate the disassembly with interleaved source-code with the command: `avr-objdump -S -D test.elf`

The disassembly of the text section shows the following disassembly **without interleaved source code**:

```
00000030 <main>:
  30:   cf 93           push    r28
  32:   df 93           push    r29
  34:   00 d0           rcall   .+0             ; 0x36 <main+0x6>
  36:   cd b7           in      r28, 0x3d       ; 61
  38:   de b7           in      r29, 0x3e       ; 62
  3a:   1a 82           std     Y+2, r1 ; 0x02
  3c:   19 82           std     Y+1, r1 ; 0x01
  3e:   0a c0           rjmp    .+20            ; 0x54 <__SREG__+0x15>
  40:   88 e3           ldi     r24, 0x38       ; 56
  42:   90 e0           ldi     r25, 0x00       ; 0
  44:   29 81           ldd     r18, Y+1        ; 0x01
  46:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
  48:   20 83           st      Z, r18
  4a:   89 81           ldd     r24, Y+1        ; 0x01
  4c:   9a 81           ldd     r25, Y+2        ; 0x02
  4e:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01       ; 1
  50:   9a 83           std     Y+2, r25        ; 0x02
  52:   89 83           std     Y+1, r24        ; 0x01
  54:   89 81           ldd     r24, Y+1        ; 0x01
  56:   9a 81           ldd     r25, Y+2        ; 0x02
  58:   84 36           cpi     r24, 0x64       ; 100
  5a:   91 05           cpc     r25, r1
  5c:   8c f3           brlt    .-30            ; 0x40 <__SREG__+0x1>
  5e:   80 e0           ldi     r24, 0x00       ; 0
  60:   90 e0           ldi     r25, 0x00       ; 0
  62:   0f 90           pop     r0
  64:   0f 90           pop     r0
  66:   df 91           pop     r29
  68:   cf 91           pop     r28
  6a:   08 95           ret
```

The disassembly makes somewhat sense, only that I miss the interleaved source code.

Interestingly enough, the output also includes a stab section, where I also find the main segment disassembled:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main() {
  30:   20 00           .word   0x0020  ; ????
  32:   00 00           nop
  34:   80 00           .word   0x0080  ; ????
  36:   00 00           nop
  38:   00 00           nop
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
  3a:   00 00           nop
  3c:   40 00           .word   0x0040  ; ????
  3e:   00 00           nop
        PORTB=i;
  40:   80 00           .word   0x0080  ; ????
  42:   00 00           nop
  44:   00 00           nop
  46:   00 00           nop
  48:   5a 00           .word   0x005a  ; ????
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
  4a:   00 00           nop
  4c:   80 00           .word   0x0080  ; ????
  4e:   00 00           nop
  50:   00 00           nop
  52:   00 00           nop
  54:   91 00           .word   0x0091  ; ????
  56:   00 00           nop
  58:   80 00           .word   0x0080  ; ????
  5a:   00 00           nop
  5c:   00 00           nop
  5e:   00 00           nop
  60:   b7 00           .word   0x00b7  ; ????
    }

}
```

Now the output **includes source code, but the disassembly is wrong**.

How do I get an output were both is correct: the disassembled instructions and the interleaved source-code?

(avr-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0. [Interleave Assembly and Source for avr-objdump](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18429/interleave-assembly-and-source-for-avr-objdump) does not seem to have the problem, although he's using the same compiler flags...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .stabs section contains debugging info, not actual code. There is no
point in trying to “disassemble” it. The `-D` option of avr-objdump
means “disassemble everything, whether or not you believe it's machine
code”. Not what you want. For your purpose, `-S` should be enough.

I do not know why your `main()` is displayed without source code. I
tried your exact same program with the exact same commands and I do see
the source interleaved with the assembly. I am using avr-gcc 5.4.0 and
avr-objdump 2.26.20160125 as shipped on Ubuntu Eoan.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, if I downgrade the compiler to 5.4.0 it works as well. I'll try to pinpoint the version that introduced the problem and report a bug once I'm able to reproduce it in a clean environment.